# ¿Cómo mockear una property de un objeto mockeado con Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy haciendo un unittest y quiero mockear un objeto. Este objeto tiene un método que tiene el decorador `@property` y cuando se usa quiero que me devuelva algo especifico.

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de configurar el `return_value` de esa `property`? En la documentacion oficial aparece algo raro con type:

```
type(m).foo = p
```

Pero no me queda muy claro porqué hay que hacer eso. ¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo encarar el asunto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes la siguiente clase:

```
class Algo:
    @property
    def nombre(self):
        return 'Soy la clase Algo'
```

Simplemente reemplazando el valor debería funcionar, no necesitas usar `return_value`:

```
import mock
import unittest

import ruta.hacia.la.clase


@mock.patch('ruta.hacia.la.clase.Algo')
class testAlgo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_algo_nombre(self, algo):
        algo().nombre = 'Diferente'

        self.assertEquals('Diferente', algo().nombre)
```